# access excel programmatically, run a ODBC query, save data, do vlookups

Tags: php, python, excel, odbc, vlookup

I am looking for a way to automate an entire process that uses Excel & ODBC queries. I know that Excel can use to a ODBC driver to run queries against a Mysql database. But I need this query to be triggered programmatically.

The individual steps the program or script should be able to do are:
1. Open Excel file
2. Run Mysql query (query will not change but the values the query hits the database for will come from the excel file)
3. Save results of the query to the Excel file as a sheet
4. Use the results to do vlookups against another sheet in the same excel file
5. save results of vlookups and close the file

Flexible on the language or any add-ons necessary. Anything out there that would help? I am looking to run this both on windows and mac.

Comment: Excel 10 for windows
Open Excel latest version for Mac

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is probably possible using COM ([Python tutorial](http://www.pythonexcels.com/2009/10/python-excel-mini-cookbook/)).  It will be messy, hard to code and hard to debug.  And no way it'll work on a mac.

Instead, if I was you I would try and take the problem out of excel.  For instance in Python, I would first directly access [mysql](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/).  I would then parse my second xls file using [xlrd](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd).  With the results of the mysql query and the parsed xls file both in Python data structures, replicating the behaviour of VLOOKUP is easy.  I would then write the results to my output xls file using [xlwt](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt/0.7.2).

Comment: Would you suggest using COM in the case of Windows? instead of Mac?